# Python Pandas: Index is overlapped? How to fix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have created a dataframe after importing weather data, now called "weather".

The end goal is to be able to view data for specific month and year.

It started like this:[image]

Then I ran `weather = weather.T` to transform the graph making it look like:
[image]

Then I ran `weather.columns=weather.iloc[0]` to make the graph look like:
[image]

But the "year" column and "month" column are located in the index (i think?). How would i get it so it looks like:
[image]

Thanks for looking! Will appreciate any help :)

**Please note I will remove the first row with the years in it. So don't worry about this part**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just means the `pd.Index` object underlying your `pd.DataFrame` object, unbeknownst to you, has a name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': [2016, 2017, 2018],
                   'JAN': [1, 2, 3],
                   'FEB': [4, 5, 6],
                   'MAR': [7, 8, 9]})

df.columns.name = 'month'
df = df.T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]

print(df)

YEAR   2016  2017  2018
month                  
YEAR   2016  2017  2018
JAN       1     2     3
FEB       4     5     6
MAR       7     8     9
```

If this really bothers you, you can use `reset_index` to elevate your index to a series and then drop the extra heading row. You can, at the same time, remove the column name:

```
df = df.reset_index().drop(0)
df.columns.name = ''

print(df)

  month  2016  2017  2018
1   JAN     1     2     3
2   FEB     4     5     6
3   MAR     7     8     9
```

Comment: @AJohnston, No problem, if this helped feel free to accept (tick on left) so other users know.

Comment: *edit* Thanks! That's how I planned on it looking :) To ask a follow up question.. how would you select the "5" value under "FEB" and "2017"? Thanks

Comment: `df.loc[df['month'] == 'FEB', 2017].iat[0]` might be sufficient, or `df[2017].iat[1]`.

Comment: Thanks again! Another follow up if you don't mind 

How would I store that? 
`Feb = weather.loc[weather['month'] == 'FEB', 2017].iat[0]` Doesn't seem to work, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not sure, what you're trying should work but if you're unable to figure it out after a while free free to [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).